# Image after a menu item

Tags: menuitem

I have added an image - > after each item in my menu but I want it to display so that the menu item is justified on the left and the images are all justified to the right.

Like this:

```
item 1       >
longer item  >
another item >
last         >
```

I currently have this:

```
item 1>
longer item>
another item>
last>
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Can you perhaps add a language tag to your question?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a style of `float: right` to the images and set the container element to `position: relative`